# Google Colab cannot access Github private repositories

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm trying to save my colab notebook to a private Github repository, but it, and all of my other private repositories, do not appear in the dropdown list when I click "Save a copy to Github." Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: Colab now supports Github private repositories.

Comment: i hope these articles can help because they explain the process step by step:   https://arunkprasad.com/log/how-to-use-private-repos-with-colab/ and https://felixbmuller.medium.com/connect-a-private-github-repository-with-google-colab-via-a-deploy-key-cca8ad13007#:~:text=Creating%20the%20Deploy%20Key&text=Now%20go%20to%20GitHub%20and,pub%20into%20the%20key%20field.

Answer (score 36):

I encountered the same problem. You should give colab access to your private data to fix it:

1. Go to colab main page [colab.research.google.com](https://colab.research.google.com/).
2. Go to GitHub tab.
3. Check the checkbox with the label "include private repos".
4. Then colab will request access to your private GitHub data, you should provide it.
5. After this you should see private repos in a list when you try to save a notebook in GitHub.

Comment: If after following the instructions above you go back
to the page where you had your Colab notebook open and doing Save > Save a copy in Github, you still don't see the private Repositories, then refresh the page of the notebook.

Answer (score 4):

to clarify: you have to go to open notebook and then to the github tab, there you can enable private repositories. After this you can save your notebook to a private repository.

Answer (score 3):

Loading Private Notebooks
Loading a notebook from a private GitHub repository is possible,

but requires an additional step to allow Colab to access your files.
Do the following:

Navigate to http://colab.research.google.com/github.

Click the "**Include Private Repos**" checkbox.

In the popup window, **sign-in to your Github account** and authorize Colab to read the private files.

Your private repositories and notebooks will now be available via the github navigation pane.

Answer (score 2):

Answered on https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/124#issuecomment-380971797
Currently you'll need to either use a public repo or download the ipynb (File -> Download .ipynb) and manually upload your file to GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, now collab supports github private repositories. They changed the path, the correct one is: `Tools->Preferences->Request GitHub`

Answer (score 1):

I did the following instruction for connecting from colab to a private github repo.

In google colab:

1. `!ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your email address"`
2. `!cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`  (leave the answers empty by pressing enter)
3. copy result from step 2. (the result starts with `ssh-rsa`)
4. paste it here: github setting -> SSH and GPG keys -> New SSH key
5. In colab: `!ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`
6. clone your repo as follows:
   `!git clone git@github.com:{username}/{repo}.git`